Does forced movement trigger Polearm Master's Reactive Strike?
Polearm Master used to grant an opportunity attack when a creature entered your reach:

While you are wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, quarterstaff, or spear, other creatures provoke an opportunity attack from you when they enter the reach you have with that weapon.

Under the 2014 rules, this meant that forced movement did not trigger a polearm attack. However, 2024 Polearm Master does not use an Opportunity Attack:

Reactive Strike. While you’re holding a Quarterstaff, a Spear, or a weapon that has the Heavy and Reach properties, you can take a Reaction to make one melee attack against a creature that enters the reach you have with that weapon.

Does this imply that the Reactive Strike can be triggered by forced movement like Shove, Push weapons, Repelling Blast, Thunderwave, Dissonant Whispers, Turn, etc.?

Yes
You've quoted all the relevant text that applies and you're correct that Polearm Master (PAM) doesn't have an exception for forced movement.
This is likely done to allow players to utilize the various weapon masteries and other non-attack roll options to create more dynamic battles that allow parties to benefit from teamwork.

To address some questions in the comments, the language for Opportunity Attacks specifically exempts forced movement from triggering them:

You also don’t provoke an Opportunity Attack when you Teleport or when you are moved without using your movement, action, Bonus Action, or Reaction. For example, you don’t provoke an Opportunity Attack if an explosion hurls you out of a foe’s reach or if you fall past an enemy.

As indicated by the language of PAM, this additional attack is not an Opportunity Attack, rather it's a Reactive Strike and subject to specific rules for that.
By comparison, consider the language for War Caster:

Reactive Spell. When a creature provokes an Opportunity Attack from you by leaving your reach, you can take a Reaction to cast a spell at the creature rather than making an Opportunity Attack.

or Sentinel:

Guardian. Immediately after a creature within 5 feet of you takes the Disengage action or hits a target other than you with an attack, you can make an Opportunity Attack against that creature.

Both feats specifically use the defined term of Opportunity Attack. Therefore, the absence of such language in PAM indicates that it is not the same thing. It is plausible that such a change was made to prevent the combo of Opportunity Attacks from PAM and Sentinel being used to hit enemies before they approach and locking them in place.

Are there no rules that mention forced movement? It seems like forced movement got a massive buff

@SeriousBri not within the language of PAM there's not.

@Tarod thanks for the suggestion. Added.

I wasn't thinking specifically within the language of PAM, I was more thinking about somewhere else in the rules. General movement rules maybe. You showing the opportunity attack rules specifically still call out forced movement works for me though. +1 now.

What immediately jumped out to me, with it now using a reaction, you can only trigger the effect once between rounds, unlike before where you could in some cases trigger it infinitely so long as the condition was met. Buffed in some cases, but more reasonable in most other cases
